# How can I create an inherited property in a metro app

Tags: wpf, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In a WPF application, I can create an inherited property by using the FrameworkPropertyMetadata:

```
property = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached (..., new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (..., FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits)
```

However, I can't find FrameworkPropertyMetadata when writing a windows 8 metro app.
Does it exist?
Is it accomplished in a different way

Comment: can't be done in metro xaml. Metro Xaml is based of Silevrlight, so good starting point is to see if it is possible to do in Silverlight. If answer is no, then most likely it is not possible in metro xaml either.

Comment: Come on, anybody found a workaround? Like implementing a DP-changedCallback that recurses through the children or whatsoever? Or assigning a style to something very basic like FrameworkElement, that forwards the attached property to its content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't do that. If you look at [the documentation for `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701833.aspx), you will notice it takes a [`PropertyMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.propertymetadata.aspx). But there is no way to set the `Inherits` flag or anything similar.